# joomla developing question

Tags: joomla1.5

Can someone give me some insight on a scenario like this.

Say a company has en existing Joomla site, not complete but just has all the modules, plug-ins, and components installed that they believe they will need.

If someone new where to come in and given the general idea of what the site needs to do, and by accomplishing this they need to make sure all plug-ins share data between each other update information between each other when ever one module is updated. As well as fixing and modifying the template to take shape and form of how they envision the site to be interacted with.

Would jumping into this project be more trouble than its worth? Would creating something from the ground up using custom developed pages rather than using Joomla as a back-end/front-end be too much of a hassle.

Also given that the existing installation has 301 tables to sot through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla is more than just a CMS, it is also a pretty solid "Development Framework". Modifying existing software will be faster rather than developing from scratch, especially if it is that big.

Read more about [Software Development Process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_process), it will help you with your evaluation. As far as I remember development cost is 2x less $ than maintenance in first 5 years.

Starting from the ground up can be not such a good idea for a large project. Working with another framework will result in "reinventing the wheel" and introduce new problems and will require more time for user acceptance.

I know too little to point you in the right direction... 1st of all Joomla is terrific choice, object oriented, it is extensive and very powerful. MVC architecture is huge plus. Plug-in system is easy and extensive. Modules are easy and customizable.

I suggest using Zend  Framework if you want to "reinvent the wheel". ZF is exceptional choice but your cost will be MUCH higher. You will have all similar functionality and features like in Joomla: OO, MVC, singletons, layouts, placeholders, modules (components), plug-ins, etc... Comparing ZF to Joomla's "Development Framework" is like comparing Ferrari to Honda Civic.

Long story short: I would try to stick with Joomla and create my library extending Joomla's classes... this will help automating a lot of things (reduce code, etc...). If I was to give a quote to the client I would try to see what they want/their experiences with existing project (check with their IT department, etc). If experience was horrible from day 1 and it was because of software and not hosting/db/hardware/network/etc then I would give 2 quotes: 1st for recreating in Joomla, 2nd for recreating in Zend... and explain strength/weaknesses of both. If software behaved 'OK', with minor to medium problems/bugs/errors I would reuse existing project.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Hmmm, I see your point. I have developed a large amount of projects and really was always afraid to jump into joomla because of its complexity. The 'client' wants a fully functional social network catering to their industry. This is what is causing me some internal confusion because at first glance I would think i'd be better to create the site from scratch and making the CMS specific to how 'I' make the site. I tried joomla for a bit in the last few days and I find it exhausting to try to connect modules and components together through the database. What would you recomment?

Comment: Well... I worked with Joomla for over 3 years. Positioning conditional modules can become complex. I would look into following component on Joomla before attempting to create from scratch: JomSocial (very powerful and growing SSN component), hwdVideoShare (Youtube like, integrates with JomSocial to create user channels), sh404SEF - the BEST SEF, Kunena or Agora for forum, K2 for blog/news, aiContactSafe (custom contact forms),  XMAP. The are best of the best components, I use most of them very often for clients/etc..

Comment: As per your modules... you can create your own SUPER module which will be displayed on every page (in setting), but the content will be dynamic. This simplifies things when it comes to dynamic pages that are not part of the menu system + you can make it async to speed things up.